# How do I lock a web app's functionality to certain computers/devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I wrote a delivery web app using PHP, mySQL, javascript and jQuery for a pharmacy where they can type up the deliveries on the computer, go out and make the actual delivery, and have the customers sign on the drivers phone with their finger. I am now integrating new functionality into this site to keep track of how many hours each employee worked, by allowing them to log in and click "clock in" and then click "clock out" at the end of their shift. The problem I am having now is that we don't want the employees to be able to "clock in" or "clock out" at home, but we still need them to be able to access the site from anywhere to capture signatures for the deliveries.

I thought of a couple solutions, but there seems to be no way to implement them. My solutions where:

1. Allow the admin account to "activate clock in/out ability" by clicking a button which would save a file to a discrete location. The site would find this file when the non-admin accounts are using the site on that computer, and allow them to clock in. It seems like this is a security issue with javascript and isn't doable.
2. Allow the admin account to "activate clock in/out ability" by clicking a button which would record some unique identifier to that machine and save it to the database. When a non-admin logs in, the site would check the database for this value and compare it to the value of the machine to grant access to the "clock in/out" feature.

I think the most common solution people would use is the IP address, but I don't think that would work because the Pharmacy has dynamic IP.

Does anyone know how to make either of my two solutions work, or have a different idea to have the same result?

If this isn't the right place to post this type of question, can someone suggest somewhere else I could post it?

Comment: You're looking for cookies.  (or, if you want to be fancy, client certificates)

Comment: Cookies are too temporary i think. they can be too easily removed by clearing browsing history etc. Client certificates might be the answer though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can save info to the user's browser using HTML5 Web Storage, or Local Storage. It is like a cookie, except doesn't expire or get cleared when the browser closes or computer shuts down. I'm thinking if i use this the same way as my original plan, it will work. The only downside would be if the user clears their browser history, this will get wiped with it. I think this will be the lesser of the evils since I don't think the pharmacy ever clears their browser history.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

I will check this answer off if/when I decide to go with this solution, which it's looking like I probably will.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML5 geolocation to see if they are actually inside the pharmacy. Whether the employees' devices support this you would have to check, but there is an HTML5 API

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (result) {
    console.log("Lat: " + result.latitude + " Long:" + result.longitude);
});
```

Another option would be to have a daily changing clock in / out password posted at the pharmacy. The employees would have to be at the pharmacy to see what it is to be able to clock in.

Yet another and perhaps the simplest option is just to have a traditional clock in / out machine physically at the pharmacy ;)

Comment: Geolocation might be good enough. Not what i had in mind, but if all else fails that might work. Posting a daily password would work, but I know the managers are going to be too lazy to do that. And a physical machine is kind of out of the question haha

Comment: What if you make them scan the bar code of one of the products with their phone? I wasn't sure but I'm assuming here the "clock in" is the beginning of delivery.

Comment: No they are actually two different "modules" if you will. This is just to record how many hours they work for payroll. I might be able to think of a solution with the barcode, that's a good idea, but I already have a delivery program (VB) in place that's causing some issues (which is why I'm creating this module) so they are more used to just going to the computer and logging in.